# How do I create multiple topics/queues in multiple servicebuses with bicep?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-bicep

I don't quite understand the relationship between parent and child components when working with bicep and more specifically arrays.
The error I get is this: Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/p6vklkczz4qlm' at line '54' and column '9' is defined multiple times in a template.

The error is quite clear I just don't understand the solution I guess.

main.bicep

```
param servicebuses array = [
  'servicebus_dev'
  'servicebus_acc'
  'servicebus_prod'
]

resource servicebusNamespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2021-11-01' = [for servicebus in servicebuses: {
  location: location
  name: servicebus
  sku:{
    name: 'Standard' 
    }  
}]

module topicModule 'topicsModule.bicep' = [for servicebus in servicebuses:{
  name: uniqueString('topic')
  params:{
    parentResource: servicebus
  }
}]
```

topicsModule.bicep

```
param topics array = [
  'topic1'
  'topic2'
  'topic3'
]

param parentResource string

resource topicResource 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2021-11-01' = [for topic in topics : {
  name: topic
  }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the topics in a module makes it a bit cumbersome. You have to fetch the namespace using the existing keyword and then you can add a parent relationship to your topic to create it within the given namespace.

```
resource servicebusNamespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2021-11-01' existing = {
  name: parentResource
}

resource topicResource 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2021-11-01' = [for topic in topics : {
  parent: servicebusNamespace
  name: topic
      }]
```

Then you have to make your topicModules name dependent on the selected servicebus and also add a dependsOn for the servicebus namespace so that bicep will know to deploy the namespace first.

```
module topicModule 'topicsModule.bicep' = [for servicebus in servicebuses:{
  name: uniqueString(servicebus)
  dependsOn:[
    servicebusNamespace
  ]
  params:{
    parentResource: servicebus
  }
}]
```

I guess you replaced your real service bus namespace names with dummy values but just in case, make sure to use a name thats more likely to be globally unique and don't use the _ character, it is not allowed in the name of a service bus namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the accepted answer.

A topic is a sub resource of service namespace so the resource name looks like that:
`servicebus-namespace-name/topic-name`

topicsModule.bicep file:

```bicep
param servicebusName string

param topics array = [
  'topic1'
  'topic2'
  'topic3'
]

resource servicebus 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2021-11-01' existing = {
  name: servicebusName
}

resource topicResource 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2021-11-01' = [for topic in topics: {
  name: topic
  parent: servicebus
}]
```

In the main file, you can just invoke the module like that:

```bicep
module topicModule 'topicsModule.bicep' = [for (servicebus, i) in servicebuses: {
  name: uniqueString(servicebus)
  params: {
    servicebusName: servicebusNamespace[i].name
  }
}]
```

Here you don't need to specify the `dependsOn` as it is automatically generated by bicep at compile time.