# How do I create multiple subscriptions with rules in multiple topics using bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

My goal here is to create multiple topics with multiple subscriptions and every subscription has its own rule(an sqlfilter in this case).
The below solution which doesn't work renders this exception:
*Internal Error - System.NotImplementedException: Mismatch between count of index expressions and inaccessible symbols during array access index expression rewriting.
Am I using the namespace rule totally wrong or what am I missing? The NotImplementedException really makes it all confusing to me.
I'm using Bicep version 0.6.1. I have not tested an older version of bicep yet but will definitely do so.

```
param topics array = [
  'customerevents'
  'ekonomievents'
  'orderevents'
]

var customerSubs = json(loadTextContent('./objects/customerSubscriptions.json'))

param parentResource string

resource servicebusNamespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2021-11-01' existing = {
  name: parentResource
}

resource topicResource 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2021-11-01' = [for topic in topics : {
  name: topic
  parent: servicebusNamespace
  }]
  
resource subscriptionCustomer 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions@2021-11-01' = [for (subscription, i) in customerSubs : {
  name: subscription.name
  dependsOn: topicResource
  parent: topicResource[0]
}]

resource subscriptionCustomerRules 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions/rules@2021-11-01' = [for (subscription, i) in customerSubs : {
  name: uniqueString(subscription.name)
  parent: subscriptionCustomer[i]
  properties:{
    filterType:'SqlFilter'
    sqlFilter: {
      sqlExpression: '1=1'
      requiresPreprocessing: false
    }
  }
}]
```

Comment: I imagine it is related to this other SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72097533/how-do-i-create-multiple-topics-queues-in-multiple-servicebuses-with-bicep?

Comment: Also is it a bicep execption in VS code, at build/compile time of after the deployment is submitted ?

Comment: I do get the same exception when compiling the bicep-file directly in a console so I'd say it's not the VS Code-extension that's causing the error.

Comment: could you add the entire bicep file please?  it will help you reproduce the issue. And also if you could add the bicep version you are using it will be helpful

Comment: may also need the customerSubscriptions.json file if you can

Comment: Just from the quick look, I think there is a problem with parent in `subscriptionCustomer` (`parent: topicResource[0]`). Do you really want the first topic (index 0)? We do not know the data in JSON files, but if every subscription there has topic name it is for, the parent can be `parent: topicResource[subscription.topic]`. And you do not need index `i` in this loop. Also I would try to do it in smaller steps. First just topics and subscriptions and if that work, try add rules.